# Crash with WebRtc in Aandroid

Tags: android, crash, webrtc

use webrtc in android sometimes it would crash when stared .I can saw the video preview not display.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error during updateTexImage (see logcat for details)
                                                                       at android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.nativeUpdateTexImage(Native Method)
                                                                       at android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.updateTexImage(SurfaceTexture.java:169)
                                                                       at org.webrtc.SurfaceTextureHelper.updateTexImage(SurfaceTextureHelper.java:244)
                                                                       at org.webrtc.SurfaceTextureHelper.tryDeliverTextureFrame(SurfaceTextureHelper.java:258)
                                                                       at org.webrtc.SurfaceTextureHelper.access$500(SurfaceTextureHelper.java:36)
                                                                       at org.webrtc.SurfaceTextureHelper$3.onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTextureHelper.java:132)
                                                                       at android.graphics.SurfaceTexture$EventHandler.handleMessage(SurfaceTexture.java:296)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: What do you use for the rtc?

Comment: library is libjingle. The phenomenon is video preview failed.     `org.webrtc.Logging: SurfaceViewRenderer: local_video_view: updateSurfaceSize. Layout size: 446x335, frame size: 176x146, requested surface size: 176x132, old surface size: 0x0
E/IMGSRV: :0: gralloc_module_createfence: Failed to merge mapper sync fds
E/IMGSRV: :0: QueueCancelBufferWrapper: Failed to create buffer sync object`

Comment: Please post additional info like the manifest.xml, the activity/fragment that initialises the view.

Answer (score 0):

@Kyle Emmanuel

post additional here.

fragment  xml:

```
`<RelativeLayout  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent">  
    <org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer  
        android:id="@+id/local_video_view" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>`
```

use code like ApprtcDemo

```
`private VideoTrack createVideoTrack(VideoCapturer capturer) {
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "before updateTextImage");
        videoSource = factory.createVideoSource(capturer);
        capturer.startCapture(videoWidth, videoHeight, videoFps);
        localVideoTrack = factory.createVideoTrack(VIDEO_TRACK_ID, videoSource);
        localVideoTrack.setEnabled(renderVideo);
        localVideoTrack.addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(localRender));
        Log.i(TAG, "after updateTextImage");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "create videoTrack fail");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return localVideoTrack;
}`
```

I track the log ,into `capturer.startCapture` and use `SurfaceTexture.nativeUpdateTexImage` . 
    sometime running normally ,sometimes crash.

```
difference,crash had this log

 E/IMGSRV: :0: gralloc_module_createfence: Failed to merge mapper sync fds
 E/IMGSRV: :0: QueueCancelBufferWrapper: Failed to create buffer sync object
```

Answer (score 0):

did you find the reason ? I meets the same situtation
android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.nativeUpdateTexImage(Native Method)
2
android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.updateTexImage(SurfaceTexture.java:244)
3
org.webrtc.SurfaceTextureHelper.updateTexImage(SurfaceTextureHelper.java:2)
4
org.webrtc.SurfaceTextureHelper.tryDeliverTextureFrame(SurfaceTextureHelper.java:18)
5
org.webrtc.SurfaceTextureHelper.a(SurfaceTextureHelper.java:2)
6
org.webrtc.SurfaceTextureHelper.lambda$wYEXO-2G7y97X63YT4GvOb7CuC4(SurfaceTextureHelper.java)
7
org.webrtc.-$$Lambda$SurfaceTextureHelper$wYEXO-2G7y97X63YT4GvOb7CuC4.onFrameAvailable(lambda)
8
android.graphics.SurfaceTexture$1.handleMessage(SurfaceTexture.java:207)
9
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
10
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
11
android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30137434)